# Why is Apple example BTLE-transfer ipad app's RSSI value so bad?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am having trouble getting Apple's core Bluetooth BTLE-transfer app example working because the RSSI signal strength from peripheral to central is below the level allowed by the Central app (-35db).

I have the v1.0 Apple BTLE-transfer core Bluetooth example app running on two brand new iPad minis, and the RSSI is usually too low ( < -35 db) even when they are side by side.

Oddly, my two ipad minis w iOS 6.1.2  sometimes drift above -35 for a few seconds (range is like -15 to -35ish), then below again;
and my two other ipad minis w iOS 6.1.3 never get above -35 (actual range is -48 to -36).

If I change the -35db limit downward so that they connect, it still doesn't work because:
"Connecting to peripheral ''."
...so there is actually no real connection.

Comment: Are you trying to write your own app? What are you trying to achieve with this question? Just so you know, connections via btle on ios can occur even as low as -110db

Comment: Yes, am writing my own app.  What I'm trying to achieve is to learn if anyone has found a WORKAROUND for the bug in Apple's Bluetooth central peripheral transfer app causing weak (< -35db) peripheral sending signal strenth.  I initiated an Apple engineering bug report, and Apple has duplicated the problem in their lab.